# How to gitignore the files that get generated when you compile in Visual Stuido 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, gitignore

I'm currently using the `.gitignore` file from [GitHub](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) but every time I compile my project in Visual Studio I get a bunch of files generated.

These are the files that get generated every time I compile.

> MyApp/bin/Debug/MyApp.exe
>
> MyApp/bin/Debug/MyApp.exe.CodeAnalysisLog.xml
>
> MyApp/bin/Debug/MyApp.pdb
>
> MyApp/obj/Debug/Views/MyApp.exe
>
> MyApp/obj/Debug/MyApp.g.resources
>
> MyApp/obj/Debug/MyApp.pdb
>
> MyApp/obj/Debug/Views/ReportsView.baml
>
> MyApp/obj/Debug/Views/ReportsView.g.cs
>
> MyApp/obj/Debug/Views/ReportsView.g.i.cs

Is this normal behavior?
Is there a way to include these files in my `.gitignore` file so they get ignored when committing changes in Git?

Comment: Yes, it is completely normal that Visual Studio generates files when you compile your code. Yes, you can put those files in .gitignore - I'm not sure what the problem here is?

Comment: What does `git status` report?  Are these files _untracked_ or do they have _unstaged changes_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add those 2 entries to [the `.gitignore` file](https://gist.github.com/kmorcinek/2710267) to ignore the generated files (obj and bin directories) during build

```
[Oo]bj/
[Bb]in/
```

Now they are not shown as modified.

Comment: Added the following three folders to my **gitignore** `bin/, obj/, Debug/` and that made the trick.